# What are the pros and cons of using .ttf fonts in an ios application

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, fonts, uifont

Has anyone used `.ttf` fonts in an ios application?

What are the pros and cons?

Are they better than using regular `fonts`? My fonts appear blurred on iPhone 6.

Comment: we can install custom fonts as per requirement. As some fonts are not available in Xcode.

Comment: If you use dynamic type, you ought to adjust some things for custom fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Let us look at the pros and cons of using custom `.ttf` fonts in iOS application

Pros:

- Custom fonts allow us to include fonts that are not given by IDE.
- With custom fonts we can give user an **attractive UI**, so far that is the main purpose of using custom fonts in our app.

Cons:

- Custom font need to be included into your resource folder, it will **lag** your application at the time of startup.

These are some two points I came through so far.

Comment: Cause lag at startup? Bit of an exaggeration ;)

Comment: Yes every custom font file cause delay at the time of app startup. I have been through this lag so said and found so many developers with same delay. M i wrong about this point?

Comment: Interesting, I either didnt notice or it only happens w/ some fonts.

Comment: Try monitoring startup time in console , it will be differ by seconds.

Comment: Do we have concept of ttf images in ios? If yes, then does it affect the UI and performance?

Comment: yes you can use image ttf file. Performance will be affected by size of ttf file. UI is totally depends on you how you want it to be. To use image ttf you need to know the character that the font is using.

Comment: @Dev_Tandel can you please elaborate how we can use that?

Comment: You have .ttf file? Just import as regular .ttf file. Do specify in info.plist